# How to pass userpref variables in an igoogle widget

Tags: php, xml, variables, get, igoogle

Hi I've made my igoogle app simple though it is basically using an xml/php file and getting a series of articles and displaying them. Simple and nice.

Now I just need to finish it off with passing how many stories the use would like to show.
I've got the dropdown working for when they click edit settings in the google area but I'm at a loss on how to pass the information back to my php/xml file and display the number of stories the user has selected.

Can anyone help.

Comment: i wonder can you create html in the widget ?

Comment: Yes you can - and that's what I've done google then just displays the html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a brief document about working with userpref. it may help you. Check this [Google document](http://code.google.com/apis/gadgets/docs/fundamentals.html#Datatypes) and also they listed how to deal with remote content in two type GET AND POST, check this document also [working with remote content](http://code.google.com/apis/gadgets/docs/remote-content.html#methods-post)

Comment: Thanks although I have to say that I think that 
1. Google Aps aren't very easy to make.
2. The way I got around this was to user content type =url then I could use userprefs and with a little hard graft it all worked - just a little too much work for my liking though.

Answer (score 0):

do a `<form>`

with auto-submit

```
<select name='myfield' onchange='this.form.submit()'>
<option .... >
...
</select>
</form>
```

then you got `$_POST['myfield']`

Comment: Ah I see what you mean - but in the igoogle they want you to use some userprefshttp://code.google.com/apis/gadgets/docs/reference.html#Userprefs_Ref which work with the igoogle widget edit - there seems to be a refresh but I can't get the variables into my php script. Also people can then save these vars as well.

Comment: after you get these values in the first time you save them as $_SESSION and this can help with JS/PHP var transfer http://forums.digitalpoint.com/showthread.php?t=16822

Comment: That could work but feels like I'm going against what igoogle has already given and what happens when they leave - the session is lost that's not how igoogle works. - Check igoogle out see what you think.

Comment: i will check it out and i'll come back with better answer